# Java Exception doesn't have the same exception message returned from db2 console?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, zos

I want to insert multiple rows in a table from a console/tool (e.g.: Data studio) I get the following error message

> THE INSERT OR UPDATE VALUE OF FOREIGN KEY FK$MAR$S IS INVALID.
>   SQLCODE=-530, SQLSTATE=23503, DRIVER=4.13.111

This means I have some trouble with a FOREIGN KEY variable, but **I solved that** later and it works well.

My problem is that when I'm running the same query from a Java application using `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()` (batch because it could insert more than one row at a time), I get a different error message:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.wn: [jcc][t4][102][10040][3.57.82] Batch failure.
>   The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an
>   individual member of the batch.  Use getNextException() to retrieve
>   the exceptions for specific batched elements. ERRORCODE=-4228,
>   SQLSTATE=null

When I used `getNextException()`, I get the following:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.co: A NON-ATOMIC INSERT STATEMENT ATTEMPTED TO
>   PROCESS MULTIPLE ROWS OF DATA, BUT ERRORS OCCURRED

And the error code is -4228.

Why this difference? I want the java application return the same error details as the console tool, so I can handle those exceptions in my java code.

For example, if the returned error code=-803 which means duplicate exception, I would handle my code to make update instead of insert, or if the returned message contains some words like " FOREIGN KEY ", I'll tell user to make sure about lookup tables and so on

I use DB2 version 10.5.3 on z/OS and the DB2 driver version is : 3.65.92

Comment: 4.3.11 *or* 3.65.92 ?? (there seems to be confusion)... and why would you expect the same error(message), when you fixed it..?;)

Comment: driver is 3.65.92 , and i'm expecting the same message as i wand to handle my code based on the returned error message . for Example : if the returned error code=-803 which means duplicate exception , i would handle my code to make update instead off insert , or if the returned message contains some words like " FOREIGN KEY " i'll tell user to make sure about lookup tables .. and so on

Comment: @Bassant There is no such a db2 version on z/OS: 10.5.3. Is this 10.5 for LUW or 10 for z/OS?

Comment: yes, it's 10.5.

Comment: Exceptions can have causes, and `SQLException` can have multiple exception chained onto the original. Make sure that you analyse everything by using 1) `exception.printStackTrace()`, and call `getNextException()`, print its stacktrace, and then call `getNextException()` on that exception, and repeat that until `null` is returned. You can also iterate over all exceptions and their causes (eg `for (Throwable t : yourSQLException) { System.out.println(t); }` to just print the messages)

Answer (score 2):

```
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            if (ex instanceof com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable) {
                com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable db2ex = (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Diagnosable) ex;
                com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Sqlca sqlca = db2ex.getSqlca();
                if (sqlca != null) {
                  System.out.println("SQLCODE: " + sqlca.getSqlCode());
                  System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + sqlca.getMessage());
                } else {
                  System.out.println("Error code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
                  System.out.println("Error msg : " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
              System.out.println("Error code (non-db2): " + ex.getErrorCode());
              System.out.println("Error msg  (non-db2): " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            ex = ex.getNextException();
        }
        ...
    }
```

Above is an example of handling db2 exceptions. The example of output when there are 2 violations simultaneously: unique key on the table `MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE` where batch inserts come, and a foreign key on a parent table. I split it intentionally into 2 parts:

Before `getNextException()`:

> Error code: -4229
>
> Error msg : [jcc][t4][102][10040][4.19.66] ... getNextException().
>   ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null

After `getNextException()`:

> SQLCODE: -803
>
> MESSAGE: One or more values in the INSERT statement,
>   UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement
>   are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique
>   index identified by "1" constrains table "MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE" from
>   having duplicate values for the index key.. SQLCODE=-803,
>   SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=4.19.66
>
> SQLCODE: -530
>
> MESSAGE: The insert or update value of the FOREIGN KEY
>   "MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE.MYTABLE_FK" is not equal to any value of the parent
>   key of the parent table.. SQLCODE=-530, SQLSTATE=23503, DRIVER=4.19.66

Answer (score 1):

I think the batch exception message is pretty clear. Consider that different statements in a batch might fail or issue warnings for different reasons. The batch level error message is therefore generic and instructs you to use "getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific" statements in the batch.

Comment: useing getNextException()  :
 com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.co: A NON-ATOMIC INSERT STATEMENT ATTEMPTED TO PROCESS MULTIPLE ROWS OF DATA, BUT ERRORS OCCURRED and the error code is -4228

and i don't want to get that message ,i want the error detail to be specific as the console one

Comment: Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old thread. I will share the code which worked for me

```
 try{
preparedStatement.batchUpdate( new ClassName{
//code with setting values and batch size});
}catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
                BatchUpdateException be = (BatchUpdateException) e.getCause();
                SQLException current = be.getNextException();
                do {
                    current.printStackTrace();
                } while ((current = current.getNextException()) != null);
            }
        }
```

In here I'm trying to get the exception based on BatchUpdateException instance.